# Python Excel writter overwrites multiple sheets with last one

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I have a dataframe df with value as column name containing 3 query as below

'Select * from sales'
'Select * from product'
'Select * from inventory'

I am running the query in a loop so that one query runs one at a time

```
For I in range (1, 4) :
   j = df['Value'][I]
   Q = "{}".format(j) 
   R= ctx.Cursor().execute(q) 
   C= pd.Dataframe(R.fetchall()) 

   With pd.Dataframe(r'sample.xlsx') as written:
       Rfst = ('sheet -{}').format(I)    
       C.to_excel(writter, sheetname=rfst, index = false)
```

The step after  `Q` iam using a variable and `ctx` cursor to execute the query and then assigning the query output to dataframe `C` which is working fine with a loop.
The problem occurs when I am writing the dataframe to excel with the sheet name as the loop value,`I`.

The `rfst` variable will be based on the value of `I`.

But the resulting excel file only has the last page, sheet 3. The first two are overwritten. The file should contain sheet 1,sheet 2 and sheet 3. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please fix indentation and syntax/grammar (`For`? `With`?) for compilable Python code and include all variable asaignments (`writter`?).

Comment: Use the [**`pandas.ExcelWriter`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) object to save multiple data frames to single workbook (a regularly asked Pandas question).